# css3 transition with margin-left auto in ff/opera

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a `#header`-element with `margin: 0 auto`. I added a media-query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
 #header {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-out; 
 -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
 margin-left: 0;
 }
}
```

`-moz` and `-o` ignore the transition attributes: `margin-left` is set immediately to `0`, while `-webkit` behaves as expected. 
When using a numeral instead of `auto`, firefox and opera do apply the transition.

How do I make Mozilla and Opera apply the transition while still using `auto`?

Comment: Working for me at OSX FF in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heSmW/).

Maybe you didn't close the media-query's brace? You certainly didn't in your given code, but I don't know if it's a typo...

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, I corrected it. Your fiddle does work for opera, but not for ff. I'm on a windows machine.

Comment: @scumah: Using a higher duration-time (starting ~1.2s) did resolve the issue in your fiddle for ff, but not in my own setting. With a duration-time of 1.1s, it arbitrarily partly works sometimes.

Comment: Hm, that's strange, I didn't know FF had those issues... I'm sorry to say that I have no windows pc available and can't test it :/

Answer (score 0):

Using `-moz-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.58, 1) 0s;` seems to work on Firefox on Ubuntu. (That's how Opera interpreted `ease-out`.) Try it on Windows.

Comment: That didn't resolve the issue. I think this is what my rule gets internally translated to anyway.